# couldn't get glossaries to work (SOLVED)

Tags: glossaries

**SOLVED**

> The cause of the problem was the `include(s)` at top of my main tex file, i changed them to `input` and now it works.

I've read the documentation of the glossary package and a lot of examples (g.e. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633016/glossaries-package-and-footnote-in-latex), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426835/example-for-a-simple-latex-glossary)), but my glossary items will be referenced, the glossary itself otherwise won't be printed. All the other indexes/toc are working. Has someone an idea?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries} 

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bar}{name={bar}, description={\ldots}}
\newglossaryentry{baz}{name={baz},description={\ldots}}

\newacronym{foobar}{foobar}{\ldots}

\begin{document}
\section{foo section}
Lorem ipsum \gls{bar} \gls{baz} and \gls{foobar}.

\printglossary[type=main,title={Glossary},toctitle={Glossary}]
\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations},toctitle={List of Abbreviations}]

\end{document}
```

Below the one that makes problems:

Makefile:

```
all:
xelatex thesis
biber thesis
makeglossaries thesis
xelatex thesis
```

thesis.tex

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\include{header/header}
\include{header/commands}
\include{header/settings}

\makeglossaries
\bibliography{bibliography/thesisbib}

\include{appendix/glossary}

\begin{document}
\input{variables/global}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
    \input{frontpage/frontpage}
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\input{frontpage/title_backside}
\newpage

{
    \onehalfspacing
    \input{abstract}
}
\blankpage{\thesisBlankPageText}

\tableofcontents
\blankpage{\thesisBlankPageText}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{foo}    
\section{bar}    
\gls{computer} is a machine and \gls{mah}, \gls{aca}.
\blankpage

\appendix 
\pagenumbering{Alph}

\cleardoublepage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Glossar}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=main,title={Glossary},toctitle={Glossary}]

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\input{bibliography/bibliography}
\end{document}
```

glossary.tex:

```
\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
  name=computer,
  description={\ldots}
}
\newglossaryentry{mah}
{
  name=mah,
  description={\ldots}
}
\newacronym{aca}{aca}{a contrived acronym}
```

Comment: You should provide a compilable example, so that one can reproduce your issue.

Comment: What are all those `\include`s doing in the preamble?  If they are files containing 'personal' commands and so forth, you should name them `.sty` and load them as normal packages `\usepackage`.  (Note this is not likely the source of your problem, but it is impossible to tell since we don't know what's in them.  If they are not related to the problem, you should remove them from a [minimal(!) example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528); and if they are related, then you need to elaborate on their contents.)

Comment: It also looks like you are calling your bibliography twice..?

Comment: @jon Using `\input` is perfectly fine; surely `\include` is out of place in the preamble.

Comment: Ok, i see that i've switched the use cases for \include and \input, \include.

@jon:
The `header/header include`, includes a file with all the `\usepackage` declarations, `header/commands` consits of only one command to make "intentionally blank pages" and the third one (settings) sets the `\arraystretch` value to `1.2`
All except the header include, can be ignored.

Comment: @egreg -- Ah, I've never tried `\include`in the preamble; not surprising if it's doesn't work, etc.  I know `\input` works of course, but I'd still recommend loading personal definitions via `\usepackage` as an example of best practice (in normal circumstances).  But what I meant was that the *content* of these packages might be the source of the problems, and that can't be known unless they are explicitly excluded by the OP or their contents given.

Comment: Does `makeglossaries` produce any error messages? Are there any errors in the glossary log files (`.glg` etc)?

Comment: I have no problems compiling your new MWE. What's yours with it?